# How to open the camera with more than one button click in Android?

Tags: java, android

I created camera application in Android. I have created one activity and 3 buttons and 3 image view are included in the same activity. When I have to take snap click on first button that snap will display in first image view, then when I take snap on click second button that snap will display in second  image view and same as to third button.

When I run my app camera open success fully and take the snap also done but it can't display in image view same as to another buttons also. Here is my code.

Here is my Activity Code

```
public class Take_Snap_Page extends Activity
{
    ImageView imgPersonalSnap;
    ImageView imgAddressProofSnap;
    ImageView imgPanCardProofSnap;
    ImageView imgHideBitmap;

    Button btnPersonal ;
    Button btnAddress;
    Button btnPanCard;
    Button btnSubmitSnap;

    Bitmap bp;
    Bitmap bitmap ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.take_snap);

        imgPersonalSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagesPersonnalSnap);
        imgAddressProofSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAddressProofSnap);
        imgPanCardProofSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePanCardproofSnap);
        imgHideBitmap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgHide);



        btnPersonal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_Personal_Snap);
        btnPersonal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open();

                imgPersonalSnap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        });




        btnAddress = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_AddressSnap);
        btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open();

            }
        });



        btnPanCard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_PanCardSnap);
        btnPanCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open();

            }
        });

    }


    public void open() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null )
                {
                    // ... now let's see use the picture at data/
                    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgHideBitmap.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHideBitmap.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();


                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this,

```
package com.example.linkedin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Take_Snap_Page extends Activity
{
    ImageView imgPersonalSnap;
    ImageView imgAddressProofSnap;
    ImageView imgPanCardProofSnap;
    ImageView imgHideBitmap;

    Button btnPersonal ;
    Button btnAddress;
    Button btnPanCard;
    Button btnSubmitSnap;

    Bitmap bp;
    Bitmap bitmap ;

    private int FIRSTCLICK=1;
    private int SECONDCLICK=2;
    private int THIEDCLICK=3;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.take_snap);

        imgPersonalSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagesPersonnalSnap);
        imgAddressProofSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAddressProofSnap);
        imgPanCardProofSnap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePanCardproofSnap);
        imgHideBitmap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgHide);



        btnPersonal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_Personal_Snap);
        btnPersonal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open(FIRSTCLICK);
            }
        });




        btnAddress = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_AddressSnap);
        btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open(SECONDCLICK);

            }
        });



        btnPanCard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture_PanCardSnap);
        btnPanCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                open(THIEDCLICK);

            }
        });

    }


    public void open(int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == FIRSTCLICK)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null )
            {
                // ... now let's see use the picture at data/
                imgPersonalSnap.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
            }
        }else if (requestCode == FIRSTCLICK)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null )
            {
                // ... now let's see use the picture at data/
                imgAddressProofSnap.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
            }
        }else if (requestCode == FIRSTCLICK)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null )
            {
                // ... now let's see use the picture at data/
                imgPanCardProofSnap.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wit `requestCode` as like following.

```
btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            open(0);

        }
    });

btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            open(1);

        }
    });

btnPanCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            open(2);

        }
    });
```

And

```
public void open(int requestCode) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null )
            {
                // ... now let's see use the picture at data/
                switch(requestCode){
                  case 0:
                    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgPersonalSnap.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHideBitmap.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgAddressProofSnap.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHideBitmap.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imgPanCardProofSnap.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHideBitmap.getDrawable();
                    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                    break;

                }

            }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know what happend